# Determine thread wait time in WinDbg with user-mode dump

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

is there any way in WinDbg to determine since what date/time a Windows thread is blocked by functions like `WaitForSingleObjects` or `WaitForMultipleObjects`?

I know how to do this in kernel debugging (using `!thread`), but I have no idea how to do this in user-mode debugging.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In WinDbg, you can use `!runaway` to get thread timings:

```
!runaway
!runaway 1
```

(user time)

```
!runaway 2
```

(kernel time)

```
!runaway 4
```

(elapsed time)

(You'll find these documented as 0, 1 and 2 some places, but in my experience those don't work.  Perhaps it depends on the WinDbg version or something...)

You can compute the time spent suspended by subtracting a thread's user and kernel time from it's elapsed time, but unfortunately I don't know of any way (short of writing a WinDbg plugin) to get WinDbg to do that for you.

If you're not set on WinDbg, you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to get the same information.  When you right-click a process and select the threads tab in the properties dialog, you get a list of all the threads in the process.  Selecting a particular thread will show the same timing information, among other things.

Comment: What I actually wanted to know is: since what date and time is a thread blocked by a WaitFor*() function? Sorry for the imprecise question; I now have changed "how long" to "since what date/time". Anyway, many thanks for your reply.

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible.  Of course, if it's your own application you can record the current time just before you wait on something, then use WinDbg to inspect the variable where you keep it, or just print it out to a log or something.